# How to clear all the MAILER-DAEMON messages from a kubernetes pod postfix queue

Tags: bash, postfix, kubernetes

There is a domain foo.com which causing a lot of mailer-daemon mails, so i would like to clear those mails from the kubernets pods postfix mail queue. i have wrote a script, but i'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

```
kubectl config use-context <context-name>

kubectl exec postfix-pod-0 -n <namespace> -- postqueue -p | grep -B2 foo.com | grep MAILER-DAEMON | awk {'print $1'} > q.txt

cat q.txt | xargs -n1 'kubectl exec postfix-pod-0 -n <namespace> -- /usr/sbin/postsuper -d - '
```

I am successfully getting the queue id's of all the MAILER-DAEMON from the second command. But not sure about whether the xargs pass those queue id's one by one from q.txt to the postsuper.

if I get a working script for this, i am hoping to create a script to clear all the foo.com MAILER-DAEMON mails from all the pods in that cluster.

Comment: That's not the right way to do it. Ignoring error messages never ends well. Fix the problem with `foo.com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl -n namespace exec -ti postfix-pod-0 -- /bin/sh -c "postqueue -j | grep ${DEL_ADDR} | jq -r .queue_id | xargs -I {} postsuper -d {}"
```

Descroption. After "--" write run command, in this case /bin/sh with parameters.

```
kubectl -n namespace exec -ti postfix-pod-0 --
```

Shell command with pipes in double quotes will run on pod:

```
/bin/sh -c "command"
```

Get postfix queue in json format. Avery printed line is json object:

```
postqueue -j
```

Now we can get necessary lines via grep command and pass to jq.

```
grep ${DEL_ADDR}
```

In jq get message id value:

```
jq -r .queue_id
```

Next we pass queue_id to xarg and remove it via postsuper -d:

```
xargs -I {} postsuper -d {}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer, to add a (brief) explanation?

Comment: More convenient:   kubectl -n namespace exec -ti postfix-pod -- /bin/sh -c "postqueue -j | jq -s -r --arg JQSENDER ${VAR_RM_ADDR} '.[] | select(.sender==\$JQSENDER) | .queue_id' | xargs -I {} postsuper -d {}"